# Can't use VHD in a particular machine

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-virtual-pc, vhd

(All the machines referred below have Windows 7 Professional.)

I have a virtual machine targetted for Virtual PC. I'm able to use that disk in two different machines (32 bit and 64 bit, respectively).

Yet in the machine where I wanted to finally install this virtual machine I get the error that the VHD file is not valid.

- The faulty machine is 32 bit and has the exact same Virtual PC version as the other machines.
- The file was correctly copied (SHA1sum says so).
- Default XP Mode works (therefore Virtual PC is not so wrong)

Does anyone have any idea what might be wrong in the target machine?